# Connect 4 game in C

Tags: c

For a small project we need to make a connect four game. Our project is broken up into several parts with each week we are assigned a different part to work on.

This week we have to make up the work on the columns by this I mean we have to use a function is called get_column, and use this to read a valid column number from the user where the next piece will be played.

So we were supplied the following files connect4.h (File used to store functions), week8_object.o (ignore the name its just the current week of sem), and week8.c which is the file I am currently editing.

**Note 1: The comment in the code is what the lecturer wrote for us as a note.**

When I am compiling I get an error saying undeclared identifier for the `if(column_full(board, col)==FALSE)` statement (FALSE part). I thought this was declared in the .h file?

EDIT- After some googling I have found that people silence that error by having this in the header. Is it correct to have this in coherence with the .h file?:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "connect4.h" 
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

/* get_move

Prompts the user to enter a column, then checks that
 - the column is in the valid range (1-COLS)
 - that the column is not full (use function column_full to check)

If an invalid column is entered, the user is reprompted until it is valid

Returns the column number between 1 and COLS
*/

int column_full ( int board[COLS][ROWS], int col ) { return TRUE;}

int get_move ( int board[COLS][ROWS] ){

    int col;

    printf("Please enter a column number:");
    scanf("%d",&col);

    if(col>=1 && col<=COLS){
        if(column_full(board, col)==FALSE){
            printf("You have placed a token in the %d column\n",col);
        }
        else{
            printf("That column is full");
        }
    }
    while(col<=0 || col>COLS){
        printf("Your token has not been placed");
        printf("Please enter a valid column: ");
        scanf("%d",&col);
    }
    return(col);
}
```

Header file:

```
#ifndef CONNECT4_H
#define CONNEXT4_H 1

#define ROWS 6
#define COLS 7

// displays the board to the screen
int display_board ( int[COLS][ROWS] ) ;

// sets up the board to an empty state
int setup_board ( int[COLS][ROWS] ) ;

// Returns TRUE if the specified column in the board is completely full
// FALSE otherwise
// col should be between 1 and COLS
int column_full ( int[COLS][ROWS], int col ) ;

// prompts the user to enter a move, and checks that it is valid
// for the supplied board and board size
// Returns the column that the user has entered, once it is valid (1-COLS)
int get_move ( int[COLS][ROWS] ) ;

// adds a token of the given value (1 or 2) to the board at the
// given column (col between 1 and COLS inclusive)
// Returns 0 if successful, -1 otherwise
int add_move ( int b[COLS][ROWS], int col, int colour ) ;

// determines who (if anybody) has won.  Returns the player id of the
// winner, otherwise 0
int winner ( int[COLS][ROWS] ) ;

// determines if the board is completely full or not
int board_full ( int[COLS][ROWS] ) ;


#endif
```

Comment: "Have I called it correctly? "  No.  Rather than `if(column_full=FALSE)`, use `if(column_full(board, col)=FALSE)`.  Certainly your compiler must be complaining - enable all warnings.

Comment: Oh I see, and I am assuming the same thing for column_full=TRUE should have column_full(board, col)=TRUE)? I have not been able to compile the program due to some complications with the project hence why I am unable to error check.

Comment: "... not been able to compile the program due to ..." is weak.  There are many download-able compilers (gcc) and on-line compilers ( ideone.com)  Strongly recommend to compile before posting.  Your post was well formed, but it is really something for your compiler to do.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean for it to come out like that. This is part of a project that we are doing for my school right now. The lecturer has given us the files pre-compiled which he has made, (a custom header file, an object file and of course an empty c document for us to fill in as I have done) the problem is he designed this to be done at the school labs in which we use Raspberry Pi's the object file he made and compiled is only for the Raspberry Pi architecture (or whatever you want to call it) therefore I cannot compile or do anything of the sort on my macbook. Hence why I am unable to check.

Comment: He also cannot give me the object file in .c format for me to compile as it contains the answers for the rest of the semester. I have asked him to compile a mac version for me but as usual he has not responded.

Comment: You _can_ compile your .c file with the header file as suggested.  The compilation will eventually complain about missing functions like `display_board()` as code does not have those function definitions.  Yet your compilation will error/warn about the many issues in your code before then - and that would save you time.

Comment: I compiled your code and received `if(column_full=FALSE) { error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment, :else(column_full = TRUE) error  lvalue required as left operand of assignment, else(column_full = TRUE) error: expected ';' before '{' token,  warning: unused variable 'ret',  warning: unused parameter 'board'`

Comment: - If an invalid column is entered or the column is full, display an appropriate
error message and ask the user to re-enter their choice, until a valid value
is entered.
- Once the column is valid, this value (between 1 and COLS) should be
returned as the result of the function.

Comment: Perhaps in the above comments, it should be `column_full(board, col)==FALSE` instead of `column_full(board, col)=FALSE`.

Comment: Your are vandalizing your own post.  This is not a "interactive correction" site.  Revert code, append new info to help solve the original problem.  Should additional problems come up, make a new post referring to this one.

Comment: @Codor Yeah that would make sense I figured out how to compile without object file so that should fix it

Comment: @chux My mistake, I shall attempt to fix it, sorry

Comment: You have an extra semi-colon that's superfluous:

` if(column_full(board, col)==FALSE){
        printf("You have placed a token in the %d column\n",col);
        }---->> *;*  <<----
        else(column_full(board, col)==TRUE){
            printf("That column is full");
        }`

Comment: @AhmedMasud Oh I did not see that there, sorry, however the error is still coming up.

Comment: Okay.... let me see if I can help :P

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: and else is NOT a function so you cannot put parentheses after it. else()

Comment: @AhmedMasud Okay thank you, even though I have fixed it up a new error has risen

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your code:

1. In get_move() function, the given condition **"If an invalid column is entered, the user is reprompted until it is valid"** is not been taken care. You might want to use while loop in case of invalid column entered.
2. column_full() in your code is called without parameters. This function takes two parameters (refer to you .h file). So, don't forget to add them in call.
3. You have to use return(col) to take care of **"Returns the column number between 1 and COLS"**

I don't want to write a code for you. It would be helpful for you in long run, if you code yourself.

Now, to answer your question:

- It is perfectly fine to have nested if-else statements.

Comment: Hi I believe I have fixed up the problems that you suggested, I am a bit confused on #3 though please refer to OP for changes.

Comment: In requirements, function get_move says "Returns the column number between 1 and COLS". However, you were using `return(0)` earlier. Now I see you changed to `return(COLS)`;. But as per requirement you are suppose to use `return(col)`.

Comment: Oh my mistake, I was using return(0) to silence some other errors that came up. So just having return(col) at the end will suffice the requirement? Extra changes have been made regarding the true and false statements .

Comment: you are almost there as per requirement.  `while(col<=0 || col>=COLS)` will consider `col=COLS` also as invalid whereas it shall be `col>COLS`.

Comment: Also `else(column_full(board, col)==TRUE)` can just be replaced just by `else`

Comment: `};` just before else need to be replaced by `}`.

Comment: Okay so I am a little confused, I should change col>=COLS, to just col>COLS? Sorry for the questions but I just don't want to loose track of what I am doing. 

Even when I remove everything inside the brackets of the else I still get the same error but now the error have the mistake point to the brackets as shown in the updated OP

Comment: if you use `col>=COLS`, even if the user entered `col` as `COLS`, the condition will be true and this also becomes invalid case. But if you use `col>COLS`, only if the user enter more than `COLS` will be considered invalid. This is the same reason of you putting `col<=0` not `col<=1`.

Comment: Oooh I see because it was "if it is greater than or equal to" how silly of me to make a mistake like that.

Comment: Oh sorry i had already upvoted however I didn't hit answer yet as I was just hoping that someone knew how I could stop the error with the else statement. @Pawan

Comment: Yeah I have to wait until I have a rep of 15 before I can do that. Thank you for your help

Comment: Perhaps `int column_full ( int[COLS][ROWS], int col )` ask for int & int as parameter. Try changing `column_full(board, col)` to `column_full(board[COLS][ROWS], col)`.

Comment: I tried that since I didn't want to bother people without trying everything however that just causes a plethora of new errors.

Comment: I overlooked a silly mistake you still have `else()`. just use on `else`.

Comment: I tried just else there but then I get this new error: 

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_column_full", referenced from:
      _get_move in week8-cc40c5.o
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: you are getting this error because you've not defined `column_full` function in your program. You have to define it to use it. At the least you can do something like `int column_full ( int board[COLS][ROWS], int col )
{
return TRUE;
}`
 in your C file. B TW, later you might need to re-define the functions as your prof ask.

Comment: Oh by that do you mean to make it like this? 
`if(column_full(board{[COLS][ROWS], int col){return TRUE}==FALSE`{

Comment: no you have to define function `column_full` just like you did for `get_move`

Comment: The get_move function was given by the lecturer so I am a little confused on what he exactly did. So would I do the same `int` to define `column_full`?

Comment: I added the  `int column_full ( int board[COLS][ROWS], int col ) ;` under the `get_move` function at the start and kept the `if(column_full(board, col)==FALSE){` the same. However i am still getting the same error

Comment: because as I said you have to write `int column_full ( int board[COLS][ROWS], int col )
{
return TRUE;
}
`

Comment: Sorry so do I have to have that within the brackets of the `if(column_full(.......)` statement where the dots are or replace it to be `if(int column_full ( int board[COLS][ROWS], int col ) { return TRUE; }`?

Answer (score 0):

From your original code:

```
    };   /* <<-- problem 1 */
    else() {
    /* ^^^^ <<-- problem 2 */
        printf("That column is full");
    }
```

Remove these and your code will compile. I won't discuss the logic issues.

So in diff notation:

```
--- connect4.c.orig 2015-09-19 14:34:36.743337010 -0400
+++ connect4.c  2015-09-19 14:34:23.488222720 -0400
@@ -24,9 +24,9 @@

     if(col>=1 && col<=COLS){
         if(column_full(board, col)==FALSE){
-        printf("You have placed a token in the %d column\n",col);
+          printf("You have placed a token in the %d column\n",col);
         }
-        else(){
+        else{
             printf("That column is full");
         }
     }
```

Comment: Oh I see so jsut to get this right I remove the lines with a minus and add those with a plus?

Comment: So using your suggested change and adding 'int column_full ( int board[COLS][ROWS], int col ) { return TRUE;}` before the `int_getmove` function seems to have fixed the else issue but now the compiler says `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: that's a linker error not a compiler error, it means that you are not including the file that contains 'int main()' function in the list of your compiled files, can you share the command-line you're using to compile the code?